# Study of convex polytopes via commutative algebra

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $P \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be any convex polytope with integral vertices, and let $M$ be the additive submonoid of $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ which is generated by $\{ (v,1) : v \in P \cap \mathbb{Z}^d \}$. Then $M$ is an affine monoid (i.e. finitely generated, torsionfree and cancellative) and all combinatorial data of $P$ are completely determined by the isomorphism class of $M$. By choosing an arbitrary commutative ring $R$, and considering the monoid ring $R[M]$ instead of $M$ we make the whole machinery of commutative algebra available for the study of $P$.

There are many interesting connections between $P$ and $R[M]$. For example, the face lattice of $P$ is anti-isomorphic to the lattice of monomial prime ideals of $R[M]$. So theoretically, we can determine faces of $P$ by studying certain prime ideals of $R[M]$. But does this also work in practice? Are there examples of polytopes $P$ (given by integral vertices) where the algebraic viewpoint makes it easier to study the combinatorics of $P$ (e.g. the face lattice, combinatorial automorphism group, etc.)? Are there famous polytopes which were defined by affine monoids and whose properties were proved by considering monoid rings?

**In short:** I would really like to see examples where polyhedral geometry benefits from commutative algebra.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What about Stanley's proof of the upper bound conjecture?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: Thank you for this hint! I was not aware of Stanley's proof, but it is indeed a beautiful example.

Comment: There is another theorem of Stanley which says that among all centrally symmetric simple polytopes cube has the minimal h-vector. This immediately implies that in that class of polytopes the cube has also the minimal number of $k$-faces for any $k$.

Comment: @semyonalesker: Thank you, this theorem is also a great example!

Answer (score 5):

The *Sturmfels correspondence* is my favorite example. It relates the toric ideal of a point configuration (which could be the vertices of your polytope) to a regular triangulation of the point configuration. It is beautifully described, e.g., in Rekha Thomas' book [*Lectures in Geometric Combinatorics*](http://www.ams.org/bookstore?co1=AND&co2=AND&co3=AND&d=BOOK&f=G&fn=105&l=100&op1=AND&op2=AND&op3=AND&p=1&pg1=&pg2=&pg3=ALLF&r=1&s1=&s2=&s3=Rekha%20Thomas&subject=genint&u=).